# How to see if Knox is tripped on Samsung S6 Edge?

Tags: root-access, verizon, samsung-knox, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I would like to check whether the Knox counter is now 0x1 on my phone.  I booted into download mode, but I see nothing there to tell me.

How can you check the state of your Knox counter on a Samsung Galaxy S6 edge for Verizon?

Comment: Boot to download mode and you will see: `Knox Warranty Void: 0` or `Knox Warranty Void: 1`

Comment: @SuperThomasLab I did boot to download mode, but there is no line saying `Knox Warranty Void:`.  Is it gone due to PingPongRoot?  If so, how can I check Knox?

Comment: @EilliamKF could you post a screenshot?

Comment: @ElliamKF if you post a screenshot of download mode then I can help you.

Comment: @SuperThomasLab I will at some point, but I don't have ready access to the phone, it belongs to someone else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turn off the device.  While device is off, Press the Power button, Volume Down, and Home buttons and hold until you see a Warning screen, press Volume Up (continue).  At the top left of the screen you'll see "Knox Warranty Void: X (0x000X)" where X is the number of times Knox has been tripped.  Your screen will say Do Not Turn Off Target, to reboot your phone safely at this point, hold the Power and Volume Down keys until your phone screen goes black and starts to reboot.